# Ubuntu Maverick vs Preload

Tags: ubuntu, performance

Does it make sense to use "preload" service in Ubuntu Maverick? 
I have it installed and running with no errors in /var/log/preload.log.

I don't like waiting much for applications to start when I click the icon. I'm even ok with having the boot time longer if it would make starting of frequently used apps instant. Exactly that is what I expect from the preload app.

However, I don't see it working. Starting Ubuntu and waiting until all loads (no disk activity), when I click Chromium icon, it still takes 5 seconds to show the main window and even more to stop the disk flashing. I have 3 GB ram.

Do I misunderstand the concept or is it just not working?

Answer (score 1):

[Improve Application Startup Times With Preload](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/07/08/improve-application-startup-times-with-preload/)

From Link:

> Preload monitors recurring
>   applications and, after establishing a
>   pattern, will preload those binaries
>   into memory at startup.  Given that it
>   also has to establish a pattern you
>   may not see a performance increase
>   immediately.  Give it some time
>   though, you’ll start to see a
>   difference soon enough!

Comment: How much time? Is two weeks enough time?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would assume a few reboot cycles would have it down.

By the way, if this answer was helpful please click the check mark to mark it as correct.

Comment: Hi, I upvoted the answer, but I don't think it's helpful for me. As I stated I've been using it for more than two weeks (every day there are a few boot cycles) and I don't see it working. So my question remains the same - does it work in Maverick, or am I doing something wrong? What should I check or expect?